# How to connect Raspberry PI 4 with camera on 64bit

Tags: camera

I want to connect the camera with raspberry pi and make a live streaming between it and the laptop, I tried to use `raspistill` but it doesn't work

So, If any one have another way ???

Comment: if you can get it working on 32 bit first and the source for what you got it working with, you should be able to adjust code until it works on 64-bit.  that said, i stick to raspberry pi os 32 bit to avoid extra work like that when possible...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I started work on 64bit and it's not working. I does not use 32 bit at all

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - what happens instead of "working"

Comment: bash: /opt/vc/bin/raspistill: No such file or directory